# Deploy Spring boot in weblogic 12c - INSTANCE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I tried to deploy an example in weblogic 12c, it is a simple spring boot app, spring-boot-weblogic, you can find it on github:

https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-weblogic

And I have strange error:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

These are the images:

[image]

The exception in log is:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1169)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: This is pretty sure a dependency issue. Did you use in your classpath another version of Spring that the one oncluded in weblogic?

Comment: I checked the weblogic version of spring, and it is org.springframework_3.1.0.jar. I'm thiking the problem is just here. I m going to search if posible to override this version.

Comment: I solve problem, I need to include WEB-INF\weblogic.xml, with content <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>, this configuration indicates load to classloader jar of web-inf before that weblogic jar.